# Trying to call ksh from plsql procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, ksh, plsqldeveloper, database-administration

Need to execute test.ksh from procedure with 4 input variables, required one output variable value from script to procedure. Not able to find much on this in online. Can any one suggest on this how to achieve.

After analysis I tried below method to achieve still no luck. Loaded below java class to Oracle DB.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class KSHCommand {

public static String executeCommand(Long param1,String param2,Long param3, Integer param4) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
    String finalCommand = "Filesystempath/test.ksh";
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(finalCommand);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                       new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

  }

}
```

### test.ksh

```
out=`/usr/bin/java test`
echo $out
```

Below is the function defined to invoke java method

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfun(param1 IN NUMBER,param2 IN   VARCHAR2,param3 IN NUMBER,param4 IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'KSHCommand.executeCommand(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.Long,java.lang.Integer) return java.lang.String';
 /;
```

Below is the query returning empty data

```
 SELECT testfun(5,'test1',6,7) FROM DUAL;
  testfun()
  ------------------------------------------------
```

If same java file is executed from file system using ./test.ksh, will get output  **test** in terminal.

Could you please let me know if there is any thing missed if it script executed from function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dbms_scheduler` - package to create an external-job with 4 arguments, pass in the arguments and then run it.
A short and good understandable sample you´ll find here https://tinky2jed.wordpress.com/technical-stuff/oracle-stuff/creating-an-oracle-job-that-runs-an-os-executable/ or here (for Windows, but it´s very similar to UX) https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/running-a-windows-batch-file-from-dbms_scheduler/

Comment: Yeah I checked because some security our schema does not have previliges to execute dbms_scheduler